# Get modification time of remote file over HTTP in Bash script

Tags: bash, http

I'm creating a simple Bash script to extract the file modification time/date of a remote file via HTTP.

Example file: `http://example.com/bar/example.pdf`

Can this be done **without** downloading the actual file? If not, what's the best alternative?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be honest, not directly.

You will have to fetch data from the remote site to get information about the file.
Usually this is done with a `HEAD` request, but some (most?) servers haven't implemented it correctly and deliver the whole file, just like doing a `GET` request.
Assuming that you have `curl` installed:

```
curl -s -v -X HEAD http://foo.com/bar/baz.pdf 2>&1 | grep '^< Last-Modified:'
```

might give you what you want, but as said, it highly depends on the server.

Comment: "Most"? I would be surprised if *any* of the popular HTTP servers violated the protocol in such a way.

Comment: It should have changed of course. Some time ago, when I dealt with such problems, it was like that. However, time passes. If you find sites that are still running cgi whatever "apps", they are most likely not handling `HEAD`. Nevertheless, also those sites will give you the result, because they are supposed to deliver everything.

Comment: I suggest using the `--head` option instead of `-X HEAD` as its more terse so the command would become:

`curl -s -v --head http://foo.com/bar/baz.pdf 2>&1 | grep '^< Last-Modified:'`

Comment: `curl -svX HEAD` is even more terse...

Comment: I don't think this is true. [Wget has an option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html) to download a file only when it changed. Hence there's a way to fetch just the modified date. **UPD**: also there's «-I» option to `curl`

Comment: @Hi-Angel No, there generally isn't. Wget uses the If-Modified-Since header to say "hey only send that file if it's newer than this date", it's then up to the server to implement and respect that header. If the server thinks the file hasn't changed it sends a 304 NOT MODIFIED response.

Comment: `grep  -i '^< Last-Modified:'| cut -d" " -f 3-` will deal with lower case headers, and strip off the header text

Comment: If I run this command the prompt doesn't return, what's the cause of this?

Comment: Stale connection? What happens if you run simple curl only, i.e. without 2>&1... ?

Comment: If HTTP servers don't respect the protocol, what could be the point of browser caching?

Answer (score 22):

The server response does usually have `Last-Modified` field, you can check it without downloading the file. No need to use `-X HEAD`, there's a special option `-I` for that *(the `-s` suppresses progress output)*:

```
curl -sI http://example.com/bar/example.pdf | grep -i Last-Modified
```

Also in my case there's no curl installed *(I'm doing a script for an embedded device)*, just `wget`. The way with wget is:

```
wget --server-response --spider http://example.com/bar/example.pdf 2>&1 | grep -i Last-Modified
```

The `--server-response` prints headers, and the `--spider` option forces to not download pages, but rather check their existence.

Comment: This `curl` is a better answer than the accepted one. Perhaps using `grep -i` since often the "last-modified" has a different case.

Comment: @not2qubit thx for the note, edited.

Comment: For Google Colab files, there is no 'Last-Modified', but there is a 'Date' line that functions the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The man-page tells `--head` fetches the header only, than i do not need `-v` for verbose, but `-s` for silent mode is good for a bash-script:

```
curl -s --head http://example.com/bar/example.pdf
```

﻿